# Magento 1.9 installation error - PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded

Tags: magento-1.9, php, mcrypt

I have configured php_mcrypt, still getting same error.

[image]

How to solve the error?

Note : phpinfo not showing details about mcrypt.

Comment: Restart the Wampp server and try again.

Comment: yes, i did still getting the same error.

Comment: FYI - My phpinfo not showing mcrypt

Comment: for php my_crypt, check with the phpinfo whether it is enabled or not & also please flush the cache & check the version of php.

Comment: extension=php_mcrypt.dll in uncommented in php.ini file?

Comment: @AbhishekTripathi My phpinfo not showing mcrypt, how can i flush the cache?

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: @Sumit yes, In my php.ini file uncommended => extension=php_mcrypt.dll

Comment: @AbhishekTripathi php 7.2.18

Comment: FYI to all: Downgrade my version 7.2.18 to 7.1.29, after installed successfully then upgraded my version back to 7.2.18, now working, i don't know what happened, anyone knows pls explain?

Answer (score 0):

***Warning : This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 7.1.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.2.0.***

> Alternatives to this feature include:
>
> - Sodium (available as of PHP 7.2.0)
> - OpenSSL

https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php

Comment: My php ver 7.2.18

Comment: 1. Stop All Services  2. Start All Services And check Again

Comment: I did all possibilities no help, finally do some changes in versions worked, even i don't know what happened.

Comment: okay now you can just find "mcrypt " in php extension  7.2.18 it's display or not?

Comment: no, it's not showing, but my Magento installed.

Comment: coz of  REMOVED in PHP 7.2.0. that was i say so just do 1. Stop All Services 2. Start All Services

Comment: okay, let me do in the future.. now i installed.

Comment: and it's working fine, issue was all services not working proper , 1. Stop All Services 2. Start All Services .. Enjoy