# Magento 1.9 not installing on ubunut 18.4 and php 7.2 PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, mcrypt

I have installed magento 2 several times on my local machine with php 7.2 and os is Ubuntut 18.40 but when i am trying to install magento 1.9 on my machine i am getting this error.

```
PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded.
```

i have tried each and every solution given on the internet and ran every command,installed 7.1 ,5.1 and re installed 7.2 but this error is still occuring

solutions i have tried are

**https://php.tutorials24x7.com/blog/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-7-on-ubuntu-1804-lts**

**https://websiteforstudents.com/install-php-7-2-mcrypt-module-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/**

and many more please give me a solid solution for solving this issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 1.9 installation error - PHP extension "mcrypt" must be loaded](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289793/magento-1-9-installation-error-php-extension-mcrypt-must-be-loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is actually for Php 7.2 or greater so i have to run  multiple xampp for installing magento 1 on my machine 
this solved my problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7Sxe7A3JRw&feature=youtu.be

:)